# Spring security 5.2: permitAll() in authorizeRequests() does not work for POST

Tags: spring-security

I have got the RestController

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/no-restriction/action")
    public String action() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @PostMapping("/no-restriction/action")
    public String action(@RequestBody String message) {
        return String.format("You posted '%s'.", message);
    }
}
```

and the configuration

```
@Bean
public OpaqueTokenIntrospector opaqueTokenIntrospector() {
    return token -> null;// TODO
}

@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration
extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> 
            authorizeRequests
                .antMatchers("/no-restriction/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken);
    }
}
```

The HTTP request `GET /no-restriction/action` (without any authorization header) returns `200 OK` and the text `hello`. But `POST /no-restriction/action` with any request body does not work, it will return `401 Unauthorized`. Why does the `POST` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably missing a CSRF-token in your post-request.

CSRF protection is enabled by default by Spring security.

But you can disable this by:

```java
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable()
          ...;
```

or

```java
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
          ...;
```