# Error 403 Spring boot POST request when i'm trying to upload a picture into the server

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, http-status-code-403

So, i'm trying to insert photos into the database but i get hit with an error 403.
In POSTMAN everything was working fine when i checked the endpoint, but when I've created the axios request the error appeared.

This is my controller in spring:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/addItem/{id}",consumes ={"multipart/form-data"})
public void addItem(@RequestPart("item") Item item, @PathVariable Integer id, @RequestPart("imageFile") MultipartFile[] file) {
    try {
       System.out.println(item);
       System.out.println(id);
       System.out.println(file);
       Set<ImageModel> images = uploadImage(file);
       item.setItemImages(images);
       itemService.addItem(item, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public Set<ImageModel> uploadImage(MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) throws IOException {
    Set<ImageModel> imageModels = new HashSet<>();
    for (MultipartFile file : multipartFiles) {
        ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel(
              file.getOriginalFilename(),
              file.getContentType(),
              file.getBytes()
        );
        imageModels.add(imageModel);
    }
    return imageModels;
}
```

This is my request in the frontend, made with axios:

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    const item = {
      name: name,
      size: size,
      condition: condition,
      price: price,
      description: description,
      itemImages: [],
    }
    formData.append('item', new Blob([JSON.stringify(item)], { type: 'application/json' }));
    formData.append('imageFile', images[0])



    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/items/addItem/1", formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Any ideas on how i might solve solve this? I've tried with different methods for front-end.
I should mention that the images are stored as a byte array.

Comment: [CSRF-token in your post-request ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580884/spring-security-5-2-permitall-in-authorizerequests-does-not-work-for-post/59594018#59594018)

Comment: hello, @DirkDeyne i have already this disabled and it still doesn't work... any other ideas? .cors().and().csrf().disable()

Answer (score 0):

The way I use for uploading images to the Spring boot backend and works very well is:

React code:

```
var imgArray : any[]=[];
```

imgArray keeps the list of images I want to send to the backend and the code below maps images to the formData.

```
imgArray.map((file:any,index) => {
formData.append("file1",file);
})

axios.post(api_image_url,formData,{
headers:{
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
}).catch((err) => {console.log("err : " + err)});
```

The server side code:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<?> addImage(@RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile[] file1)
{
for (MultipartFile file : file1) {
// The code to store the images into DB goes here    }
}
```